# .svc could not be activated. See the servers diagnostic trace logs for more information. Application error

Tags: epicorerp

I am new to the Epicor DBM role and ran into this issue today.

When looking into this, I noticed that recycling the app pool is one solution. Since we are a large production facility, that is a last resort. It will boot everyone out of Epicor, and halt production for a few minutes. We usually reboot every Sunday to avoid any down time. I also noticed another solution in the Epicor Admin Console about recycling there and could not find it. Has anyone else had this issue, and how did you resolve it?

```
The requested service, 'net.tcp://epicorapp02/EpicorERP/Erp/BO/TransOrderReceipt.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
Application Error
 
Exception caught in: mscorlib
 
Error Detail
============
Message: The requested service, 'net.tcp://epicorapp02/EpicorERP/Erp/BO/TransOrderReceipt.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
Program: CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary
Method: HandleReturnMessage
 
Client Stack Trace
==================
 
Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.DecodeFramingFault(ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IConnection connection, Uri via, String contentType, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
 
Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Open()
   at Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelEntry`1.CreateNewChannel()
   at Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelEntry`1.CreateChannel()
   at Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelEntry`1.GetContract()
   at Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ImplBase`1.GetChannel()
   at Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ImplBase`1.HandleContractBeforeCall()
   at Erp.Proxy.BO.TransOrderReceiptImpl.GetByID(Int32 packNum)
   at Erp.Adapters.TransOrderReceiptAdapter.OnGetByID(Int32 ID)
   at Ice.Lib.Framework.EpiBaseAdapter.GetByID(Int32 intId)
   at Erp.UI.App.TransOrderReceipt.Transaction.GetByPackingSlip(String packingSlip)
   at Erp.UI.App.TransOrderReceipt.Transaction.OnGetByID(String id)
   at Erp.UI.App.TransOrderReceipt.Transaction.OnValidateKeyField(Control tb)
   at Erp.UI.App.TransOrderReceipt.TransOrderReceiptForm.keyFieldValidating(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnValidating(CancelEventArgs e)
   at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraNumericEditorBase.OnValidating(CancelEventArgs e)
   at Ice.Lib.Framework.EpiNumericEditor.OnValidating(CancelEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.NotifyValidating()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformControlValidation(Boolean bulkValidation)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ValidateThroughAncestor(Control ancestorControl, Boolean preventFocusChangeOnError)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.EnterValidation(Control enterControl)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.UpdateFocusedControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.AssignActiveControlInternal(Control value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ActivateControlInternal(Control control, Boolean originator)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.SetActiveControlInternal(Control value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.set_ActiveControl(Control value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Select(Boolean directed, Boolean forward)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ProcessTabKey(Boolean forward)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
 
 
-----------------
The requested service, 'net.tcp://epicorapp02/EpicorERP/Erp/BO/NonConf.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
 
Application Error
 
Exception caught in: mscorlib
 
Error Detail
============
Message: The requested service, 'net.tcp://epicorapp02/EpicorERP/Erp/BO/NonConf.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
Program: CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary
Method: HandleReturnMessage
 
Client Stack Trace
==================
 
Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.DecodeFramingFault(ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IConnection connection, Uri via, String contentType, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
 
Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Open()
   at Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelEntry`1.CreateNewChannel()
   at Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelEntry`1.CreateChannel()
   at Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelEntry`1.GetContract()
   at Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ImplBase`1.GetChannel()
   at Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ImplBase`1.HandleContractBeforeCall()
   at Erp.Proxy.BO.NonConfImpl.GetAvailTranDocTypes(String& listAvailTranDocTypes)
   at Erp.Adapters.NonConfAdapter.GetAvailTranDocTypes(String& listAvailTranDocTypes)
```

Comment: I have found the Recycle IIS Application Pool in the Epicor Administration Console. Just not sure if that will 100% resolve it.

Comment: The issue has resolved itself, but I still do not know why this was triggered, or what is triggering it.